# Data-bind href attribute for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind anchor attributes to a KnockoutJS ViewModel field. I tried something like this:

```html
<a data-bind="href: Link, value: Title"></a>
```

but this doesn't work. Where I can get a list of possible data-bind values for html elements?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to use the [`attr`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding, this allows you to set any attribute you like.

For example:

```html
<a data-bind="attr: { href: Link, title: Title }, text: Title">xxx</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

Here you can find a list of all possible bindings.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

on the left side (sidebar) you find links to other bindings like text, attr style and more.

You can do this

`attr: { href: Link}, text: Title` like `xwrs`commented

or create a template 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Solution found <a data-bind="attr: { href: Link}, text: Title"> </a>

Answer (score 1):

As an *alternative* to [@RichardFriend's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123182/419956) (and more commonly used option), you could write a custom binding handler to make your views a wee bit more terse:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['href'] = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    element.href = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  myUrl: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
  myText: 'Stack Overflow website'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<a data-bind="href: myUrl, text: myText"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me

```
            <td class="CommandArea" rowspan="2">
            <p><a href='#' data-bind="click: abandon" >Abandon</a></p>
            </td>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain how it answers the question?